Time-based trigger just stops firing
This is the 2nd time I've had this issue with this one particular spreadsheet.
I have a time based trigger that fires every 15 minutes. 2 days ago it just stopped firing. There are no errors, if I go into the trigger settings nothing is out of the ordinary. It just doesn't fire anymore.
This exact thing happened on this same project around a month ago. I simply deleted the old Timed trigger and created a new one, and it ran fine again until it stopped working once more. Again, the trigger does NOT fail, it simply stops firing at all.
My client who owns the Spreadsheet changed their google password around the same time this happened (not sure about the first time). Would that impact it?
I don't know what to try beyond replacing the trigger, but this is not a good solution as important processes are not happening in the gap between when it stops firing and we discover it.

May I ask how long ago you started running the said script? I suspect that you have reached the limit / quota for time based triggers. Also, if possible, can you indicate the runtime for one run?

As far as I know, a total of 90 minutes is the daily runtime limit for free accounts. Was there any quota limit error or runtime error in the logs?

Thanks @PatrickdC ALL of my current clients are running free accounts, and in some cases I am almost CONSTANTLY running operations, and google has never canceled a trigger for me anywhere else. Maybe I'm just getting lucky. I got no quote limit or runtime error at all. It just fired on June 4th for the last time, without any reported errors, and there are zero logs since then.

May I confirm that you are looking at the logs in the Executions tab of Google Apps Script? It's the one with the icon with 3 horizontal lines and an arrow pointing to the right. The executions tab logs all runs from the start of execution up to the latest execution.

@PatrickdC yes I am. The last execution is over 2 days ago. Zero failures.

I see. Is it possible for you to share your script so that we may further investigate your situation? Also, can you share the settings you used when setting up the time based trigger?

Setting a time-driven trigger to run too frequently might fail for several reasons. Only Google engineers could likely know exactly what is happening, and it's unlikely that they will spend time on an isolated issue. Still, it might happen.
Look at the Google Apps Script issue tracker if you haven't done it. You can find the link at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support. If you don't find that an issue like this was already reported, create a new Issue.
In the meantime, until Google engineers solve this, you might want to implement some design changes and add some features to help the spreadsheet owner monitor the trigger status, like writing the timestamp of the last time it ran and conditional formatting to alert when it has not run as expected. Include a UI to help the spreadsheet owner delete and recreate the trigger.
Or you can explain that Google Apps Script is a best-effort service and tell them to call you whenever it stops working.
To support the "best-effort service," refer your client to Google's terms and conditions. You might also refer them to the Google Apps Script Issue Tracker.
